# ImageMagick with filenames with hyphens: "unrecognized option"

Tags: windows, command-line, imagemagick

I am trying to use ImageMagick 7.0.10 on Windows 10 v2004 to crop images to a 256×256 square.

After `cd`ing into the source folder, which has a file called "-s-u-c-k- .png - (hex-a-decimal).png", I run this command in Command Prompt:

```
magick mogrify *.png -resize 256x256^ -gravity center -extent 256x256 -path D:\Pictures\vapor\256x256png *.png
```

This throws the following error:

```
mogrify: unrecognized option `-s-u-c-k- .png - (hex-a-decimal).png' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageCommand/6353.
```

Adding the option `-define png:compression-level=9`, as suggested by [this forum post](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=35241), throws the same error:

```
D:\Pictures\Reddit\VaporwaveArt>magick mogrify *.png -verbose -define png:compression-level=9 -resize 256x256^ -gravity center -extent 256x256 -path D:\Pictures\vapor\256x256png *.png
mogrify: unrecognized option `-s-u-c-k- .png - (hex-a-decimal).png' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageCommand/6353.
```

The error seems to be caused by files that begin with a hyphen followed by a normal character, but not triggered by patterns like `-- - (drop_trout).png` or `- 2 - - (kelvin9595).jpg`. How can I successfully convert a folder with images with these sorts of file names?

Answer (score 3):

Change the expansion to include a directory path, i.e. change `*.png` to `.\*.png` or `./*.png` to reference files in the 'current' directory.

That way ImageMagick will end up receiving paths like `.\- 2 - - (kelvin9595).jpg` which no longer start with a dash.

Answer (score -1):

Use `--` to tell `cmd` where your command parameters end. e.g.

```
magick mogrify *.png -resize 256x256^ -gravity center -extent 256x256 -path D:\Pictures\vapor\256x256png -- *.png
```

Note the `--` before `*.png`

Comment: The same error happens when I run that command you suggested, or `D:\Pictures\Reddit\VaporwaveArt>magick mogrify *.png -resize 256x256^ -gravity -- center -extent 256x256 -path D:\Pictures\vapor\256x256png -- *.png`

Comment: cmd does nothing to the command line arguments. And even in bash where arguments are expanded `--` has no special meaning. It's only special inside the application that uses the arguments, for example in apps that use [GNU getopt or arg_parse](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html)